# How do I capture Uploaded files from HTML 5 multiple file input elements

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

If I have an input element like this:

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="file1" />
```

and select multiple files, the browser creates multiple files with the same 'file1' name element. It's like a multiple selection of a listbox.

So how do I capture this in ASP.NET using the Request.Files collection? The Request.Files.AllKeys collection shows all files, but the key values are all the same. Request.Files returns strings for each key but I can only retrieve the first file using the key:

```
var file = Request.Files["file1"];
```

This gives me the first file, but I can't access the others also selected in this way since they don't have a unique name. Iteration also doesn't work since Request.Files only returns keys not the actual file entries.

How do I capture these secondary files in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 5):

First, you're right that all *keys* of the Request.Files collection will be 'file1' (or whatever the name of your input element happens to be).

However you can loop through the collection by index, and retrieve the filename of each upload with the 'Filename' property of each HttpPostedFileBase object.

Each object will also contain an InputStream, and when I debug this in Visual Studio, I can see from the Length property that the stream actually contains the content of each image.

Example:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Request.Files[i].FileName);
        Console.WriteLine(Request.Files[i].InputStream.Length);
    }

    return View();
}
```

I guess the ASP.NET team didn't anticipate multi-file uploads. You could probably write an adapter class to convert Request.Files to a collection with a HttpPostedFileWrapper iterator, so you can use a for/each structure.

Comment: Yup - just posted the same thing at the same time you did. Got thrown by the keys rather than the index values. Working now!

Comment: I removed my entry since this one sums it up pretty well.

Comment: No worries, it was a great question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're using MVC, but if so, try this:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase[] files)
    {
       // Stuff with files
    }
```

Each file will have an InputStream property you can use to get access to the contents.

Also, you'll need to specify the enctype attribute:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Hope this helps.  I used similar code to handle files coming via this [jQuery file upload plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload).

Comment: Hmmm... tried this but I'm just getting null in the files parm. Files are getting there - I see 'em in the Http.Files collection's keys.

Comment: What does your form tag look like?  Or are you using an HTMLHelper?

Comment: Form action is just as your's is - no action and enctype set to multipart. The upload works (see solution I posted just now) but HttpPostedFileBase[] just doesn't return anything for me in MVC4.

Comment: Just to be clear, your parameter is named "file1" in your action method, yes?  The name attribute of the input element and the name of the parameter in your action method must match in order for MVC to bind correctly.

Comment: Duh, nope I didn't use the same name. So this means you'd have to have one HttpPostedFileBase array for each of the file controls on the page. Thanks! The other solution is better in my current case because it allows iterating over all files uploaded, but this makes sense if you have one box on a page.

Comment: If the name across several input elements of type checkbox or text is the same, the name given can be an array in the action method and MVC will automatically bind it for you.  However, in your case it sounds like you want an array of file arrays.  I'm not sure the MVC binding is that smart, but it might be worth exploring.  If it works, it will save you the hassle of digging through the request explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="File1" type="file" runat="server" size="60" multiple="" />
in .cs file HttpFileCollection uploads = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files; for (int i = 0; i < uploads.Count; i++) { HttpPostedFile upload = uploads[i]; Response.Write(@"alert('"+upload.FileName+"');"); }
```

I think this will may work...